# has_many through with condition not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a model Grade and a model User. Between grades and user is a many-to-many association through collaborations.

in user.rb

```
has_many :grades, through: :collaborations, source: :user
```

works, but i need to get only grades with attribute "archived" = false

i tryied

```
has_many :grades, through: :collaborations, source: :user, conditions: [' archived = ? ', false]
```

but it takes all the grades, in other words, the condition is ignored.

I can put in my collaborations this condition, but collaboration is in a polymorphic association with Grade and School, and a school doesn't have the archived field, and those causes an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
has_many :grades, through: :collaborations, source: :user, :conditions => { archived: false}
```

or

```
has_many :grades, through: :collaborations, source: :user, :conditions => { 'grades.archived' => false }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution. Apparently because collaboration is a polymorphic relation, you need to specify a source_type

```
 has_many :grades, through: :collaborations, source: :owner, source_type: "Grade", conditions: ['archived = ? ', false]
```