# has_many association ignores restricting condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many, hobo

I'm working on a Rails 3.0.x application (actually it's Hobo 1.3.x but that's not material to this question). Among the models, there are GraphPanes, GraphLabels, and LabelSets. A GraphPane can have GraphLabels and LabelSets. GraphLabels can belong to GraphPanes *or* LabelSets, but not both. So if a GraphLabel belongs to a LabelSet, I'd like to keep it from being associated to a GraphPane.

I am trying to enforce that with this code in the GraphPane model:

```
has_many :graph_labels, :conditions => 'label_set_id = NULL'
```

However, I'm still able to associate GraphLabels with not-null `label_set_id` with GraphPanes. Why? How can I stop this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16241015/306084) is superficially similar, but my relationship isn't polymorphic, so the nominal solution there doesn't help me.

Comment: By the way, pjmorse, I was looking into your org, the Concord Consortium, and discovered you work with the father, Andrew Zucker, of my best friend. Small world!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of `:conditions` on `has_many` is to filter the results that are passed back via the `graph_labels`, not to protect objects from being added to the association.

If you add a graph_label with no label_set_id, the association will build, but if you then ask for `graph_pane.graph_labels`, it will not return that non-condition-matching graph_label.

The has_many/belongs_to relationship is saved on the belongs_to model, graph_label, and so the parent/has_many/graph_pane does not stop the graph_label from writing whatever it wants to its graph_pane_id attribute. This delegation of responsibility is correct, although frustrating, I agree.

Now, as for how to stop this, I'm not sure. It sounds like you need some sort of validation on the graph_label object, something along the lines of not allowing a graph_pane_id to be set on a graph_label if that graph_label's label_set_id is nil. Since the has_many/belongs_to relationship is saved on the graph_label, you should write the validation on the graph_label. That way, the graph_label will not be able to be saved with a new graph_panel_id unless it fulfills the condition.

Thoughts? Questions?

Reference:
[has_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)

**Alternate Solution**

I've reread your question and I think want you want here is a polymorphic association.

```
def GraphPane < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :label_sets
  has_many :graph_labels, as: :parent
end

def LabelSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :graph_pane
  has_many :graph_labels, as: :parent
end

def GraphLabel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
end
```

That way, a GraphLabel can only have a single parent, which is what your “spec” above requires. Is there any reason not to implement the relations in this way?

Comment: Hey, that's interesting. I haven't thought of using a polymorphic relation that way.